# Grails 3 and Spring Security Maximum Concurrent Session

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.1, grails-spring-security

by default there is not an option to set maximum concurrent session propery in grails spring security plugin. That is available with spring security ([spring security session control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-concurrent-sessions)). How can i implement such functionality with grails 3 using spring security plugin?